# bash: make `du` show output similar to `ncdu`

Tags: disk-usage, ncdu

On Linux, here is some sample output from the `ncdu` NCurses Disk Usage tool:

command:

```bsh
ncdu /boot
```

```
ncdu 1.14.1 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help 
--- /boot -----------------------------------------------------
  100.2 MiB [##########]  initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic         
  100.2 MiB [######### ]  initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic
   11.2 MiB [#         ]  vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic
    9.7 MiB [          ]  vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic
    9.7 MiB [          ]  vmlinuz-5.13.0-27-generic
    9.7 MiB [          ]  vmlinuz-5.13.0-25-generic
    8.0 MiB [          ] /grub
    5.7 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.13.0-28-generic
    5.7 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.13.0-27-generic
    5.7 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.13.0-25-generic
    5.6 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.11.0-46-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.13.0-28-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.13.0-27-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.13.0-25-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.11.0-46-generic
  184.0 KiB [          ]  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
  184.0 KiB [          ]  memtest86+.elf
  180.0 KiB [          ]  memtest86+.bin
!  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
!   4.0 KiB [          ] /efi
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
```

BUT, it's a human-interactive program and that output isn't scriptable. I'd like to store it into a variable, so, how can I get similar output with `du` instead?

This is a follow-on question to my question here: [How to make `ncdu` show a quick summary of disk usage and exit?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1391610/327339)

The end-usage will look something like this:

```bsh
output_before="$(du /boot)"
# do a bunch of stuff here which reduces the size of /boot
output_after="$(du /boot)"
echo "Before:"
echo "$output_before"
echo ""
echo "After:"
echo "$output_after"
```

Here's a start, but it doesn't show the output in proper descending order of largest to smallest in size:

```bsh
du --all --max-depth=1 -h /boot
```

What I'd ideally like to see:

```
--- /boot -----------------------------------------------------
  100.2 MiB [##########]  initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic         
  100.2 MiB [######### ]  initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic
   11.2 MiB [#         ]  vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic
    9.7 MiB [          ]  vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic
    9.7 MiB [          ]  vmlinuz-5.13.0-27-generic
    9.7 MiB [          ]  vmlinuz-5.13.0-25-generic
    8.0 MiB [          ] /grub
    5.7 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.13.0-28-generic
    5.7 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.13.0-27-generic
    5.7 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.13.0-25-generic
    5.6 MiB [          ]  System.map-5.11.0-46-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.13.0-28-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.13.0-27-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.13.0-25-generic
  252.0 KiB [          ]  config-5.11.0-46-generic
  184.0 KiB [          ]  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
  184.0 KiB [          ]  memtest86+.elf
  180.0 KiB [          ]  memtest86+.bin
   16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
    4.0 KiB [          ] /efi
    0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
    0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img
    0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
    0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
```

But, the minimum acceptable answer will look something like this:

```
  100.2 MiB  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic         
  100.2 MiB  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic
   11.2 MiB  /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic
    9.7 MiB  /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic
    9.7 MiB  /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-27-generic
    9.7 MiB  /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-25-generic
    8.0 MiB  /boot/grub
    5.7 MiB  /boot/System.map-5.13.0-28-generic
    5.7 MiB  /boot/System.map-5.13.0-27-generic
    5.7 MiB  /boot/System.map-5.13.0-25-generic
    5.6 MiB  /boot/System.map-5.11.0-46-generic
  252.0 KiB  /boot/config-5.13.0-28-generic
  252.0 KiB  /boot/config-5.13.0-27-generic
  252.0 KiB  /boot/config-5.13.0-25-generic
  252.0 KiB  /boot/config-5.11.0-46-generic
  184.0 KiB  /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin
  184.0 KiB  /boot/memtest86+.elf
  180.0 KiB  /boot/memtest86+.bin
   16.0 KiB  /boot/lost+found
    4.0 KiB  /boot/efi
    0.0   B  /boot/initrd.img.old
    0.0   B  /boot/initrd.img
    0.0   B  /boot/vmlinuz.old
    0.0   B  /boot/vmlinuz
```

Comment: Can you explain what parts of it you want? Is it the `[###   ]` to indicate disk usage percentage? Is it the sorting? Is it the leading `!` and `@`, whatever they mean? Also, what would you do with this variable? How is it intended to be used? You can use `ncdu -o file` to print ncdu's output to a file and then `ncdu -f file` to display it. Is that enough?

Comment: @terdon, I've updated the question. I'm going to cache the output before running a cleanup operation, run a cleanup operation, then output the before and after snapshot to show how the size of the contents in the dir has changed. Take a look at the output of `ncdu -o file`. It's not at all the same and isn't really meant for human-viewing. It's intended to be a caching mechanism to avoid `ncdu` scanning each time you want to scan a dir.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said you can load it with `ncdu -f file`. So are you saying you just want `du -h | sort -rh`?

Comment: @terdon, yeah, that's close to it. I added an answer with that as part of it. I had no idea that `sort -h` could handle sorting by human-readable sizes, such as `9.7 MiB` vs `100 KiB`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Small `python` script that reads from `ncdu -o-`:

`read_ncdu.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, json

def sizeof_fmt(num, suffix='B'):
    for unit in ['','Ki','Mi','Gi','Ti','Pi','Ei','Zi']:
        if abs(num) < 1024.0:
            return "%3.1f%s%s" % (num, unit, suffix)
        num /= 1024.0
    return "%.1f%s%s" % (num, 'Yi', suffix)

def get_recursive(item):
    size = 0
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        name = item["name"]
        size = item["asize"]
    else:
        name = item[0]["name"]
        for sub in item:
            size += get_recursive(sub)[1]
    return (name, size)

data = json.loads(sys.stdin.read())

items=[]
for i in data[3][1:]:
    items.append(get_recursive(i))

sum_sizes = sum([item[1] for item in items])
biggest = max([item[1] for item in items])
print("------ {} --- {} -------".format(data[3][0]["name"], sizeof_fmt(sum_sizes)))

for item in sorted(items, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True):
    size=item[1]
    hsize=sizeof_fmt(item[1])
    name=item[0]
    percent=(size/sum_sizes*100)
    percent_str="({:.1f}%)".format(percent)
    
    print("{} {:8} [{}{}] {}".format(
        " " * (10 - len(str(hsize)))+ str(hsize),
        " " * (8 - len(percent_str)) + percent_str,  
        ('#' * round(size/biggest*10)),
        ('-' * round(10-size/biggest*10)),
        item[0])
    )
```

You might want to improve the script:

- Use `dsize` (disk size) instead `asize` (apparant size) if you like, or introduce arguments to the script to let the user decide.
- Make the script standalone with `os.walk()` instead of using `ncdu -o-` input.

See also [here](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/jsonfmt) for explanation of the `ncdu` json output format.

**Run:**

Make `read_ncdu.py` executable --> `chmod +x read_ncdu.py`, then you can run:

```
ncdu -o- /boot | ./read_ncdu.py
```

**Output:**

```
------ /boot --- 224.3MiB -------
   56.8MiB  (25.3%)  [##########]  initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic
   56.7MiB  (25.3%)  [##########]  initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic
   55.4MiB  (24.7%)  [##########]  initrd.img-5.11.0-46-generic
   11.2MiB  (5.0%)   [##--------]  vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic
    9.7MiB  (4.3%)   [##--------]  vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic
    9.7MiB  (4.3%)   [##--------]  vmlinuz-5.13.0-27-generic
    6.5MiB  (2.9%)   [#---------]  grub
    5.7MiB  (2.5%)   [#---------]  System.map-5.13.0-28-generic
    5.7MiB  (2.5%)   [#---------]  System.map-5.13.0-27-generic
    5.6MiB  (2.5%)   [#---------]  System.map-5.11.0-46-generic
  251.7KiB  (0.1%)   [----------]  config-5.13.0-28-generic
  251.6KiB  (0.1%)   [----------]  config-5.13.0-27-generic
  248.1KiB  (0.1%)   [----------]  config-5.11.0-46-generic
  180.6KiB  (0.1%)   [----------]  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
  180.1KiB  (0.1%)   [----------]  memtest86+.elf
  178.4KiB  (0.1%)   [----------]  memtest86+.bin
   16.0KiB  (0.0%)   [----------]  lost+found
     28.0B  (0.0%)   [----------]  initrd.img
     28.0B  (0.0%)   [----------]  initrd.img.old
     25.0B  (0.0%)   [----------]  vmlinuz
     25.0B  (0.0%)   [----------]  vmlinuz.old
```

Comment: On Ubuntu, `python` calls Python 2 while `python3` calls Python 3. So, `ncdu -o- /boot | python read_ncdu.py` results in an error since it calls Python 2 on the script. Since you already specify a hash-bang which says to use `python3`, just do this: `ncdu -o- /boot | ./read_ncdu.py` instead.

Comment: For larger sizes, ex: `100.2MiB (36.8%)`, the spacing is off since all you do is use `\t` to force the 2nd column over. Instead, can you do something to force the first column to always be 18 chars, with extra unused chars just being spaces? I know how to do that with the `printf` style print formatting, but not with the `"{}".format()` style print formatting in Python.

Comment: As you parse the output, what is `asize` vs `dsize`, and what is `ino`, in the `ncdu` output?

Comment: The `name` field doesn't seem to show the path hierarchy either, can you update your answer to explain how to interpret the ncdu JSON output?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way! I am surprised and happy to see a fully-functional `ncdu`-like solution. I'm just trying to understand it better and tweak the output formatting a bit.

Comment: Yes, sure, the output is not really complete. There are modules with which you can print nice tabular output, but for simplicity I didn't use that. Try `pandas` maybe. Check [this](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu/jsonfmt) for `ncdu` output format definititon. `asize` is apparant size, `ino` is inode number.

Comment: To quickly see the hierarchy of JSON output in a pretty format, I just figured out you can use `jq` (`sudo apt update && sudo apt install jq` on Ubuntu), like this: `ncdu -o- /boot | jq .`

Comment: I see you rejected my edit. This final print string does a better job. Give it a shot: `print("{:10} {:8} [{}{}] {}".format(sizeof_fmt(item[1]), "({:.1f}%)".format(percent),
        ('#' * round(size/biggest*10)), ('-' * round(10-size/biggest*10)), item[0]))` Try it on a directory which has entries >= 100 MiB and you'll see the difference in how the current print format doesn't have proper alignment, but this does.

Comment: Thought this will only cut, but it also extends -->  `{:10}`. Cool, thanks :-)

Comment: Improved even more, so size and percent is aligned to the right like `ncdu` :-)

Answer (score 6):

This provides the **minimum acceptable answer**, per the question:

```bsh
du --all --max-depth=1 -h /boot | sort -rh
```

Example usage, per the example in the question (but made into a "one-line" command so I can copy-paste it into the terminal without making an executable file script for it):

```bsh
output="$(du --all --max-depth=1 -h /boot | sort -rh)"; \
echo "Before:"; \
echo "$output"
```

Example output to stdout:

```
Before:
273M    /boot
101M    /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-28-generic
101M    /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-27-generic
12M /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic
9.8M    /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-28-generic
9.7M    /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-27-generic
9.7M    /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-25-generic
8.0M    /boot/grub
5.7M    /boot/System.map-5.13.0-28-generic
5.7M    /boot/System.map-5.13.0-27-generic
5.7M    /boot/System.map-5.13.0-25-generic
5.6M    /boot/System.map-5.11.0-46-generic
252K    /boot/config-5.13.0-28-generic
252K    /boot/config-5.13.0-27-generic
252K    /boot/config-5.13.0-25-generic
252K    /boot/config-5.11.0-46-generic
184K    /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin
184K    /boot/memtest86+.elf
180K    /boot/memtest86+.bin
16K /boot/lost+found
4.0K    /boot/efi
0   /boot/vmlinuz.old
0   /boot/vmlinuz
0   /boot/initrd.img.old
0   /boot/initrd.img
```

### References:

1. Thanks to [@terdon, who pointed out that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689668/bash-make-du-show-output-similar-to-ncdu/689672#comment1304110_689668) `sort -h` could handle sorting by human-readable sizes, such as `9.7 MiB` vs `100 KiB`.

### See also:

1. Q&A [pointed out by @Fabien Auréjac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689669/114401): [Server Fault: How can I sort du -h output by size](https://serverfault.com/a/156648/357116) - `sort -h` can sort the human-readable output from `du -h`

Comment: Note that busybox `sort` (what you'll find on embedded devices) does not support the `-h` option.

Comment: @Dev, are you aware of a good work-around? Would you be willing to write one? It may require leaving the output from `du` all in bytes, then sorting it, then manually parsing the first column (maybe with `awk`) to put it back into a "human readable" form. If you write a cmd that works on busybox and add it as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not that well-versed in Unix command-line utilities. I just thought it'd be useful to leave a note for future readers (and you, of course).

Answer (score 1):

du does provide the -ah option, alternatively, you can use df command with the option -h in order to get data of the percentage of space used that you can interpret via scripting.

to sort you can use the advice shown on this serveurfault post. https://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size

```
du -hs * | sort -h
```

From GNU `sort` [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort):

`-h, --human-numeric-sort    compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)`